# System of equations, containing irrational one.

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have been recently given such a system containing irrational equation. Unfortunately for me, i was unable to solve this.
$$\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x-y}=6 \\ 
x^2-y^2-x+y=12 
\end{cases}
$$
I could only find the (4;0) solution. 
I would really like to know if there is some pattern you should follow in order to solve this sort of problems. 
Thanking in advance.

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-y%5E2-x%2By%3D12%2C+sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2Bsqrt%28x-y%29%3D6), there is another solution, but the exact solution revealed the other solution involves solving a septic equation. Numerically, it is approximately $(4.12,1.54)$.

Comment: sextic ( sixth degree)  equation..

Answer (score 0):

That's **absolutely** a lot of algebra work.
$$
x^2+y^2=\left( 6-\sqrt{x-y} \right) ^2
\\
x^2+y^2=36-12\sqrt{x-y}+x-y
\\
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
 x^2+y^2+y-x=36-12\sqrt{x-y}  \quad(1)\\
 x^2-y^2+y-x=12 \quad(2)\\
\end{array} \right. 
$$
$(1)-(2)$, we have
$$
2y^2=24-12\sqrt{x-y}
\\
y^2=12-6\sqrt{x-y}
\\
y^2-12=6\sqrt{x-y}
\\
y^4-24y^2+144=36\left( x-y \right) 
\\
x=\frac{1}{36}\left( y^4-24y^2+36y+144 \right) 
\\
\frac{y^8}{1296}-\frac{y^6}{27}+\frac{y^5}{18}+\frac{23 y^4}{36}-\frac{4 y^3}{3}-\frac{14 y^2}{3}+8 y=0
$$
We can also get a polynomial for $x$ in a similar way. Generally speaking, for high degree polynomials we can hardly find a nice way to write the roots down. According to *Mathematica*'s computation, there's another real root, numerically $(4.12...,1.54...)$ and cannot be represented using radicals. So I think you have reached the limit: $(4,0)$ is the only root that can be computed by hand.